# Learning Rx: How can I parse an observable sequence of characters into an observable sequence of strings?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

This is probably really simple but I'm at the bottom of the learning curve with Rx. I've spent several hours reading articles, watching videos and writing code but I seem to have a mental block on something that seems like it should be really simple.

I'm gathering data from a serial port. I have used `Observable.FromEventPattern` to capture the `SerialDataReceived` event and convert it to an observable sequence of characters. So far so good.

Now, I want to parse that character sequence based on separator characters. There are no newlines involved, but each 'packet' of data is surrounded by a preamble and a terminator, both single characters. For the sake of argument, lets say they are braces `{` and `}`.

So if I get the character sequence 
`j` `u` `n` `k` `{` `H` `e` `l` `l` `o` `}` `j` `u` `n` `k` on my character sequence,
then I want to emit either `Hello` or `{Hello}` on my string sequence.

I'm probably missing something simple but I can't even begin to figure out how to approach this. Any suggestions please?

Comment: As an aside, read my coworker's (MS MVP C++) post on why to avoid the `DataReceived` event http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: @DaxFohl that's an interesting rant but I'd need some more substance before acting on it. He basically just says "it doesn't work" and doesn't explain how or why. In fact, I have found the class to be perfectly adequate for my uncomplicated use-case. I just set the state properties, open the port and then handle Data Received events, and it has worked well that way for me in >10 different production apps for >10 years. Perhaps I am lucky and have hit on the "happy path" but there we go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished using `Publish` and `Buffer`:

```
var source = "junk{Hello}junk{World}junk".ToObservable();
var messages = source
    .Publish(o =>
    {
        return o.Buffer(
            o.Where(c => c == '{'),
            _ => o.Where(c => c == '}'));
    })
    .Select(buffer => new string(buffer.ToArray()));
messages.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output of this is:

```
{Hello}
{World}
```

The idea is that you can use the following opening and closing selectors in the call to `Buffer`. The use of `Publish` is to make sure that all three of `Buffer`, the opening selector, and the closing selector share the same subscription.

```
source:  junk{Hello}junk{World}junk|
opening: ----{----------{----------|
closing:     ------}|
closing:                ------}|
```

Comment: window is used in the same way that Buffer is...but I agree that your answer is better. I forgot to use Publish

Comment: Thanks for that. All the lambdas make RX very hard to read and follow. In your answer, there is `_ => o.Where(...` - is the underscore just an identifier and you don't really care what it's called, or is it some special thing?

Comment: @TimLong The underscore is nothing special. It is the idiomatic way to ignore a required argument.

Comment: I would never have figured that out from the documentation. I've tried the code in my solution, it works beautifully and I can comprehend, with a bit of squinting, how it is working. The documentation page is still baffling even though I know what it is supposed to be saying to me :-o

Comment: One more question... what does the `.Publish()` do? Again, I have read the documentation page on MSDN: "Returns an observable sequence that is the result of invoking the selector on a connectable observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence.". That is just opaque to me.

Comment: @TimLong All uses of `o` inside the `Publish` lambda share a single subscription to `source`, so that subscribing to the result of `Publish` subscribes to `source` exactly once.

Comment: @TimLong I agree that the documentation is opaque by the way. The only way I learned this stuff is by reading books and blogs. You can't really learn it from the documentation. Lee Campbell's [Intro to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html) is very good and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212007%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to aggregate your so-far-received values into the aggregated string (`TAccumulate` is a `string`), and reset that string to `""` every time you get an end brace.  (I'll leave the work of implementing the aggregation function up to you).  This will produce observables like

```
j
ju
jun
junk
junk{
junk{h
junk{hi
junk{hi}
j
ju
...
```

Then you can use [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211607%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to only emit the ones that end with `}`

Then finally use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244306(v=vs.103).aspx) to get rid of the `junk`.

So in full, should be

```
IObservable<string> packetReceived = 
  serialPort.CharReceived
    .Scan(YourAggregationFunction)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith("}"))
    .Select(s => s.EverythingAfter("{"));
```

(I leave `EverythingAfter` up to you to implement as well).

Just a note, as you're experimenting with the aggregation function, it may be easier to use the `IEnumerable` interface of `string` to test it, i.e.

```
foreach (s in "junk{hi}hunk{ji}blah".Scan(YourAggregationFunction))
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Okay, here's a full working example

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var stuff = "junk{hi}junk{world}junk".ToObservable()
        .Scan("", (agg, c) => agg.EndsWith("}") ? c.ToString() : agg + c)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith("}"))
        .Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('{')));
    foreach (var thing in stuff.ToEnumerable()) {
        Console.WriteLine(thing);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for taking the time to provide an interesting answer. It really annoys me when people downvote without any explanation.

Comment: @TimLong sure, added the full example too.  I've used `Buffer` and `Publish` a few times but always have to go back and look it up to make sure it's not giving memory leaks.  I prefer sticking to simpler methods I can understand and just combining them to get what I need.  (You can decompose the above by deleting the `Where` and the `Select`, and still see what the `Scan` is doing on its own; it's not an "all-or-nothing" sort of deal).

Comment: I must say, this approach is certainly a lot more readable than @Timothy Shields' version with `Buffer()`. There might be a more subtle advantage too. If we use `LastIndexOf()` then I think this will cope with "junk{{hi}junk" (two opening braces). I'd be a bit worried about all the string operations wasting a lot of memory though.

Comment: @TimLong Yeah, in fact for serial ports you're better off avoiding Rx entirely. Get your stuff from the serial port in chunks, parse it in chunks, and call back your callback functions directly with the valid packets. I had to dump a nice Rx solution for a high-speed RS485 cxn on a smallish embedded CPU because it was just too much overhead.

Comment: I don't think performance is going to be an issue in this sitation. The data rate is typically 9600 bps and typically no more than about 1 to 10 transactions per second with small amounts of data, typically 5 to 10 characters at a time. The bottleneck is more likely be the speed of the link and the device at the other end, in this particular situation. However, one of the reasons I'm doing this is to find out whether it is a feasible approach, so if it is going to crash and burn then so be it, that will still be a valuable lesson.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the need for Publish(), can you expand on that at all? @Timothy Shields says it means that everything shares a single subscription. I have seen in my experiemtns that multiple subscribers don't work and require publish to be used, but I can't see any subscriptions being created in either of the solutions proposed. I have tried it both ways and they both work. In your solution, why would Publish() be necessary and what would it achieve?

Comment: @TimLong *Without* `Publish`, each observer is an observer not of some `packetReceived` subject, but of `charReceived.Scan...Where...Select`, so if you've got 100 subscribers, then it'll go through that whole algorithm for each subscriber for each character. Yikes! `Publish` essentially works as a cache, so you're subscribing to the end result, not to the algorithm.  I don't understand fully how it's used in the other solution though.